# Appium looks for Main file in project path and fails

Tags: java, appium

When I try to create an AndroidDriver, using Appium 2.0.1, I get  `InvalidServerInstanceException` (stacktrace below).

I have run appium-doctor and that doesn't show any issues.

I am not exclusively creating and starting an Appium server now, as I am told that Appium 2.0 will do that for me. It seems to be trying but is trying to find the `main` file in the project path, instead of the appium installation path.

I have tried re-installing Appium. I have followed all the recommended procedure to install Appium and its depedencies from npm. Cleaning the entire project and rebuilding the dependencies and then the project.

What should I do now to fix this issue?

Is there a driver capability I can add or should I be exclusively starting the server by giving the JS path, like we used to earlier?

```
io.appium.java_client.service.local.InvalidServerInstanceException: The main Appium script does not exist at '/<project path>/appium/build/lib/main.js'

    at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder.findMainScript(AppiumServiceBuilder.java:159)
    at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder.loadPathToMainScript(AppiumServiceBuilder.java:304)
    at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder.createArgs(AppiumServiceBuilder.java:360)
    at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder.createArgs(AppiumServiceBuilder.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:490)
    at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(AppiumDriverLocalService.java:92)
    at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService.buildDefaultService(AppiumDriverLocalService.java:88)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:137)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:236)
```

This is the code that I am running to create and Android driver

```
    private AppiumDriver createAndroidDriver(int deviceIndex) {
        this.capabilitiesFactory = new CapabilitiesFactory();
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = this.capabilitiesFactory.createCapabilities(this.currentTestPlatform);
        return new AndroidDriver(capabilities);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the JS path while creating AppiumDriverLocalService . Below is the code in kotlin.

```html
      val localAppiumServer = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(
            AppiumServiceBuilder().usingAnyFreePort().usingDriverExecutable(
                File(PropertiesProvider.getNodePath())
            ).withAppiumJS(File((APPIUM_JS_PATH))) // This will set the JS Path
```